# Regular expression to match 0 or more occurrences not working

Tags: c#, regex

This question may sound stupid. But I have tried several options and none of them worked.

I have the following in a string variable.

```
string myText="*someText*someAnotherText*";
```

What I mean by above is that, there can be 0 or more characters before "someText". There can be 0 or more characters after "someText" and before "someAnotherText". Finally, there can be 0 or more occurrences of any character before "someAnotherText".

I tried the following.

```
string res= Regex.Replace(searchFor.ToLower(), "*", @"\S*");
```

It didn't work.
Then I tried the following.

```
string res= Regex.Replace(searchFor.ToLower(), "*", @"\*");
```

Even that didn't work.

Can someone help pls ?
Even though I have mentioned "*" to indicate 0 or more occurrences, it says that I haven't mentioned the number of occurrences.

Comment: `string res= Regex.Replace(searchFor.ToLower(), @"\*", @".*");`

Comment: I debugged and noticed that it removes "someText" and "someAnotherText" from the string searchFor. I want to keep them as it is.

Comment: Thank You @Avinash Raj ! :)

Answer (score 12):

Unlike the DOS wildcard character, the `*` character in a regular expression means *repeat the previous item (character, group, whatever) 0 or more times.*  In your regular expression the first `*` has no preceding character, the second one follows the `t` character, so will repeat that any number of times.

To get '0 or more of any character' you need to use the composition `.*` where `.` is 'any character' and `*` is '0 or more times'.

In other words to search for `someText` followed any number of characters later by `someAnotherText` you would use the following Regex:

```
var re = new Regex(@"someText.*someAnotherText");
```

Note that unless you specify otherwise by putting start/end specifiers in (`^` for start of string, `$` for end) the Regex will match any substring of the test string.

Tests for the above, all returning true:

```
re.IsMatch("This is someText, followed by someAnotherText with text after.");
re.IsMatch("someTextsomeAnotherText");
re.IsMatch("start:someTextsomAnotherText:end");
```

And so on.

In Regex terms `*` is a quantifier.  Other quantifiers are:

```
?     Match 0 or 1
+     Match 1 or more
{n}   Match 'n' times
{n,}  Match at least 'n' times
{n,m} Match 'n' to 'm' times
```

All apply to the preceding term in the Regex.

Placing a `?` after another quantifier (including `?`) will convert it to lazy form, where it will match as few items as it can.  This will allow following terms to also match the terms you specified.

Comment: What is the use of `$`?

Comment: @Vikrant `$` is the Regex token for the end of the input.  If you put it at the end of an expression the expression will only match up to the end of input.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression to match 0 or more occurrences of any character is

`.*`

where `.` matches any single character and `*` matches zero or more occurrences of it.

*(This answer is a quick reference simplification of the current answer.)*

Comment: "where `.` matches _any single character_ and `*` _matches zero or more occurrences of it_." It is extremely confusing to say a pure wildcard will "match zero or more occurrences of **a** character" (twice)—to actually mean "any and all possible subsequent characters." To be clear, the "match-zero-or-more" `.` asterisk is an operator which _repeats matching of its preceding character (or subexpression) **in the regex**_, until constrained to stop, and has no relation to multiple occurrences of matched target letters, as implied here.